# Call validator and return valid / invalid as true/false from custom directive on focusout : Angular 5

Tags: angular, validation, angular5, directive, customvalidator

I am trying to validate one input field that the value is already exist or not in the database in angular 5.I have created one custom validator and wrapped it up in a directive so that I can use it in my DOM.Now its working while the validation fires on every keypress but I changed it on focusout method.But on focusout I am unable to return asyncInvalid = true/false or valid = true/false to my field. How can I achieve it. I am sharing my code snipped that I already built.

```
import {
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NG_VALIDATORS,
    FormsModule,
    FormGroup,
    FormControl,
    ValidatorFn,
    Validator
} from '@angular/forms';
import {
    Directive,
    forwardRef,
    Input,
    HostListener,
    Injectable,
    OnInit
} from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
    selector: '[checkAlreadyExist]',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: CheckAlreadyExist,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})


export class CheckAlreadyExist implements Validator {

    validator: ValidatorFn;
    paramToBeResolved: any;
    @Input() set eventListener(val) {
        val.subscribe((param: any) => {
            this.paramToBeResolved = param
        });
    }
    constructor() {
        this.validator = this.checkAlreadyExist();
    }
    validate(c: FormControl) {
        return null
    }

    @HostListener('focusout', ['$event.target'])
    onFocusout(c: FormControl) {
        return this.validator(c);
    }

    checkAlreadyExist(): ValidatorFn {
        return (c: FormControl) => {
            let isValid = /^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/.test(c.value);

            if (isValid) {
                return null;
            } else {
                console.log(isValid)
                return {
                    checkAlreadyExist: {
                        valid: true
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried with asyncvalidator. The main problem is

```
return
{
    checkAlreadyExist: {
        valid: true
    }
};
```

this part is not working. I am expecting whenever the form is invalid on focusout , it should also valid / invalid the form field.

p.s. I am able to see the log if the form is invalid on focusout (`console.log(isValid)`)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: May I use `markAsUnTouched` in the existing code so that it will fire it wherever this directive has been used .